# Can I inject an object that created dynamically

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I have a question regarding dependency injection.

I have a class, say:

```
class MyClass {
    MyServiceAPI serviceAPI;
    public setSession(Session session) {
         serviceAPI = new MyServiceAPI(session);     
    }
    ....
}
```

The session is created by another class which loads it from the database at runtime.

```
class MyAnotherClass {
    Myclass myClass;

    @Inject
    MyAnotherClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    public someFunction() {
        String key = <read from database>;
        Session session = new Session(key);
        myClass.setSession();
        ......
    }
}
```

As it described, the MyClass instance is injected into MyAnotherClass and the serviceAPI instance in MyClass is created using new. If I want to inject the ServiceAPI to MyClass, I can probably create it in the class where the session is created and using a setter to set it to MyClass.

But the question is that I don't really want to let the MyAnotherClass to create the MyServiceAPI and inject it to MyClass. I want the MyAnotherClass not awaring the existence of MyServiceAPI.

Is there a way I can do this using depdendency injecter like Guice or Spring? Or simply Java?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah looks like `MyClass` should be injected into `MyAnotherClass`. Also, `MyServiceAPI` should probably be injected into `MyClass`. This sort of question is hard to answer without knowing the semantics/intention of your code tho...

Comment: Yes. I understand what your mean. Sorry the question is a little bad shaped. Let me change it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do dependency injection in pure Java there is some support as of Java 6 through the built in java service provider interface. Though it requires some plumbing with jar files etc.. Have a look  [here for Java SPI](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/extensible/)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with guice and a simple factory. MyServiceAPI can be an interface.

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private MyServiceFactory factory;
    private MyServiceAPI myServiceAPI;

    public void setSession(Session session) {
        myServiceAPI = factory.createMyServiceAPI(session);
    }
}

public class MyServiceFactory {

    MyServiceAPI createMyServiceAPI(Session session) {
        // create with new, inject via Injector, do what you want... :)
        return <yourobject>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a good ol' fashioned factory for this.

```
class MyAnotherClass {
    MyClassFactory myClassFactory;

    @Inject
    MyAnotherClass( MyClassFactory myClassFactory ) {
        this.myClassFactory = myClassFactory;
    }

    public void someFunction() {
        String key = "1"; // read from DB
        myClass = myClassFactory.getMyClass( key );
    }
}

class MyClassFactory {
    public MyClass getMyClass( String key ) {
        Session session = new Session( key );
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setSession( session );
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do think you may have to re-order your dependencies. Again, without knowing your full code this is kinda difficult, but looking at your example, it seems like the following is true:

- `MyClass` actually depends on `MyServiceAPI` and NOT on `Session`. Therefore, you should just inject a `MyServiceAPI` directly in its constructor.
- `Session` should have its `sessionId` (or whatever) injected in its constructor. You can bind its value in Guice, so you'd get something like: `@Inject @SessionId public Session(String sessionId)`. Or you could have both the `sessionId` and some `SessionService` get injected into `Session`, so it can retrieve its own data from the service.
- `MyServiceAPI` should have `Session` injected into it.